# Image resize wont output image

Tags: php, image, upload

I'm attempting to resize an image before it is parsed so as to not allow big uploads and to reduce upload time. My function currently is aimed at one picture at a time.

The picture are loaded separately to determine what order they go in. Most of the images that are uploaded are 4mb and more and i'd like to reduce them to at least 200kb or less

this is what i have:

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
$maxDimW = 600;
$maxDimH = 450;
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $_FILES['photo9']
['name'] );
if ( $width > $maxDimW || $height > $maxDimH ) {
$target_filename = $_FILES['photo9']['name'];
$pic9 = $_FILES['photo9']['name'];
$size = getimagesize( $pic9 );
$ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
if( $ratio > 1) {
    $width = $maxDimW;
    $height = $maxDimH/$ratio;
} else {
    $width = $maxDimW*$ratio;
    $height = $maxDimH;
}
$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($pic9));
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], 
$size[1] );

imagejpeg($dst, $target_filename); // adjust format as needed


}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo9']['tmp_name'],$target9))
{  //Tells you if its all ok
echo "<tr width='600' height='50' halign='center' valign='center'><td>";
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been 
uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
echo "</td></tr>";
 }
 else {
 echo "<tr width='600' height='50' halign='center' valign='center'><td>";
//Gives and error if its not
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 echo "</td></tr>";
 }}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: _“and to reduce upload time”_ - this is server-side code that only comes into play _after_ the files have already been uploaded. Whatever image resizing you do here, is of course to late to affect the upload that has already happened.

Answer (score 0):

could you try `echo` or `vardump` every step's output? could you debug your php code? you can search xdebug.